# Getting multiple entities with get_by_id in ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

With the old db, I could call `Model.get_by_id([1, 2, 3])` to get a list of entities.

Ndb's `Model.get_by_id` doesn't support a list of ids as a parameter.  What's the best way to replicate the old functionality?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You use the function get_multi which takes a list of keys.

```
objects = ndb.get_multi([ndb.Key(Model, k) for k in ids])
```

Comment: It's not as elegant as before, but I guess this is the best way.  Thanks.

Comment: Makes more sense to me this way as the _multi says "give me a list".